# What is the name of this cursor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cursor

I see this cursor when I use the drag feature in the RC-tree, and I want to use it in another dragzone on my web. I don't know the name of this cursor. In another scenario, this cursor appears when you highlight text and drag it into the input link of the browser.

In addition, how can I change the mouse cursor when using the drag and drop feature in RC-tree?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be a custom cursor icon. Checkout the various cursor pointer values on [page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_cursor). Refer this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-custom-mouse-cursor-with-css-and-javascript/) to learn how to add a custom cursor icon.

Comment: If you go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) , you can see this cursor icon. I think this is window cursor.